# What is this connector on a Christmas LED chain?

Tags: connector

What is this connector type?

It is on a Christmas LED chain.  It should be IP67.

[image]

Comment: I think on bigclive's YouTube channel he noted that while these connectors are mostly used for low voltage (12 - 24v), he had found some that were used for 240v! So check the actual voltage you need because a connector type doesn't _necessarily_ dictate voltage and wiring patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this help you find the manufacturer of the connector: https://www.luminalpark.com/en-eu/4m-vintage-led-36v-extension-clable/58491 and https://www.luminalpark.com/en-eu/blog/pml-connector-change-from-ip44-to-ip67

I used google images to search the image you provide.

Comment: Links may go stale, so it helps adding some more text about how you came up with those links to start with and possibly a summary of your findings.